# Combine multiple picturebox into one retaining its position

Tags: c#, .net, save, jpeg, picturebox

[image]

I have 3 pictureBox's, Green is 1 and the two images are in two different pictureBox. I want to stitch all the picturebox's into one single .jpg image retaining the position of all the images. Can anyone help me out with the code. Scratching my head since 4 days :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0,0,pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
        pictureBox2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location.X - pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox2.Location.Y - pictureBox1.Location.Y, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height));
        pictureBox3.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(pictureBox3.Location.X - pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox3.Location.Y - pictureBox1.Location.Y, pictureBox3.Width, pictureBox3.Height));

        bmp.Save(@"C:\Temp\output.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please improve your answer with a little explanation. What does your code do, and most importantly, why does is do this?